# Spring security ant matcher doesn't restrict the endpoint to the specified role

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring security with JWT mechanism. I have this spring security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/users/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(PUT, "/answers/(\\d+)").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_INSTRUCTOR")
            .antMatchers(GET, "/answers/(\\d+)/is-correct").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_STUDENT")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()))
            .addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

Because I use JWT, I have 2 filters. One is for authentication:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        log.info("Username is: {}", username);
        log.info("Password is: {}", password);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
        String accessToken = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 2 * 60 * 1000)).withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);
        String refreshToken = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 60 * 1000)).withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .sign(algorithm);
        Map<String, String> headerTokens = new HashMap<>();
        headerTokens.put("access_token", accessToken);
        headerTokens.put("refresh_token", refreshToken);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), headerTokens);
    }
}
```

And the other one is for authorization:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
        if ("/users/register".equals(servletPath) || "/login".equals(servletPath) || "/users/refresh-token".equals(servletPath)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else { //here start the checks for authorizationn
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                try {
                    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
                    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
                    JWTVerifier jwtVerifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
                    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = jwtVerifier.verify(token);
                    String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();
                    String[] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class);
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    stream(roles).forEach(role -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role)));
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    log.error("Error logging in: {}", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());
                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                    error.put("error_message", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
                }
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I hit the GET request having an INSTRUCTOR role, the request still gets accepted. This should have been rejected by spring security but it gets accepted.
And, if I hit the PUT request having a STUDENT role, the request still gets accepted.
Do I miss something?

Comment: First of all where are your debug logs, second of all writing custom security is bad practice, there are security standards and if you are using security framework you should be using the filters that the framework offers. If you write custom filters you are on your own and dont expect that framwork functions will work since you have essentially ”opted out” of using the framework.

Comment: Spring security has had full jwt support for 3 years now, i would suggest you read the reference instead of trying to build something custom.

Comment: I know it has support but it's a project of mine where I want to learn new things. The thing is, I used @PreAuthorize("hasRole('STUDENT')") and @PreAuthorize("hasRole('INSTRUCTOR')") and it seems that this way works and also I have added .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() on the Spring security configuration. Something happens with the antMatchers that is somehow out of my league...

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying a regex (`"/answers/(\\d+)"`) to an Ant matcher.

```
.antMatchers(PUT, "/answers/(\\d+)")
```

If you don't want to change the expression, you can use a regex matcher.

```
.regexMatchers(PUT, "/answers/(\\d+)")
```

Otherwise you need to supply an [Ant path pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html).